# How to use SQLite database in Cordova for iOS?

Tags: iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-cli

Same code works for Android but it doesn't work on iOS device. I want to create an SQLite database in cross platform using SQLite plugin. it working in safari browser. but doesn't work in device.

```
onDeviceReady: function() {

    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

},

receivedEvent: function(id) {

    var shortName = 'WebSqlDB';
    var version = '1.0';
    var displayName = 'WebSqlDB';
    var maxSize = 65535;

    myDB=openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);

}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please help me i m new in cordova